# iOS Core Data optimistic lock failure false positives

Tags: ios, core-data

While debugging other problems with the core data concurrency debug flag set to 1, It came to my attention that the framework raised some exceptions during context saves.

The application I'm working on does some heavy use of background threads and private queue context to fetch data from a socket and perform heavy tasks on background.

The thing is that when I run the application without the `-com.apple.CoreData.ConcurrencyDebug 1` environment variable, I don't get any errors from the `try context.save()`

For example, I set `-com.apple.CoreData.ConcurrencyDebug 1` then I perform an action that does something and saves it.

```swift
  do {
        try context.save()
     } catch {
        log.error("Delete error: \(error)")
  }
```

I get an `optimistic lock failure` exception on the `try context.save()`

then I proceed to return the app to the same state that would have triggered the exception and run it *without* the `-com.apple.CoreData.ConcurrencyDebug 1` and setting a breakpoint

```swift
  do {
        try context.save()
     } catch {
        log.error("Delete error: \(error)") // <--- breakpoint here
  }
```

Unlike other issues I've faced in the past, there's no error whatsoever. I don't have any information of what the cause of the lock is. There could be many things going wrong but I can't figure which one it's messing things up in this opportunity.

I have googled extensively and there's not much detail on how to get meaningful info from an optimistic lock exception.

Comment: The last time I googled *Core Data optimistic locking failure* I got a lot of advice, I think it's even in Apple documentation, to set a non-ambiguous merge policy on your managed object context.  It doesn't always work in my experience, but have you done that yet?

Comment: There's a lot going on here, and switching merge policies won't cut it.
Obviously there's an architectural problem to fix, but it's difficult for me to diagnose it without having more information on what's going on.  And that's the information I'm missing out. 

I set a NSQueryGeneration to my main context and that ceased the exceptions but the UI is noticeable behind the data by far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When Using NSPersistentContainer, Cross all your T's:

- Search all your project for references to viewContext. Make sure it's only called on main thread
- Beware of NSManagedObject 'utility' extensions. Road to hell is paved with good intentions. When extending NSManagedObject, always refer to `self.managedObjectContext` if needed.
- On thread intensive applications, read from mainContext, write on background context. Be patient, don't over update/refresh/query your viewContext to gain more updates on the UI. Don't dirty read.
- Beware of 'refreshFoo'/'calculateBar' calls on NSFetchRequestController callBacks. Let data flow to your App's UI. don't pull it.